django constraint in multi-tenant application
I have a multi-tenant application where we use multi-currency.
The simplified models looks like:
class Currency(models.Model):
    multi_tenant_company = models.ForeignKey(MultiTenantCompany, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_default_currency = models.BooleanField(default=False)

Now I want to add a unique db constraint on this model where every multi_tenant_company can only have 1 default currency.
My current approach, which fails is:
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['is_default_currency', 'multi_tenant_company'],
                condition=Q(is_default_currency=True),
                name='unique_is_default_currency')
        ]

What am I missing?

It seems that the answer seems to be
class Meta:
    constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(
            fields=['multi_tenant_company'],
            condition=Q(is_default_currency=True),
            name='unique_is_default_currency')
    ]

In this version, the condition is only applied to the field multi_tenant_company uniqueness.
